# Woocommerce template and css issues

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a Wordpress custom theme, and I've been having issues with my woocommerce template rendering. Firstly, not all of the pages are showing up (some of them are reverting to the index.php and page.php files). Secondly, for the pages that are showing up (the single product page, the archive products page), the css is not being applied. I have tried everything suggested on the docs (hooks), but I have failed. Here is a link to my github for you to see the file structure.

https://github.com/naderae/elbe-collections

**possible issues wuth my code:**

my code is not written in the standard wordpress way. I only have three pages so far, index.php, page-about.php, and page-team.php, which work fine. page.php and single.php are empty. thus, my site consists of 2 pages, and index.php.

I've been struggling with this for 2 days, and would really appreciate some guidance of hoe to get me back on track. Cheers

Comment: I have seen you posted same question many times. I checked source files and your theme structure is not up to the standards. No body class, even no loop in any template. I would recommend you to see deault twentyseventeen theme and its template structure, specially index.php, page.php, single.php

Comment: @AhmadHassan I have changed the file structure, and included all the necessary files and loops. Still having the same problem. any suggestions? the updated code is in the git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a list of some basic theme templates must preset in theme, more about this in details [click here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/).

- index.php
- style.css
- header.php
- single.php
- page.php
- category.php
- archive.php
- 404.php

I would recommend you to start with some default WordPress theme like twentyseventeen theme or other. These themes will have all basic functionality of WordPress. Check functions.php in the theme folder to customize/add functionality.

for more details about Template Hierarchy [click here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

**Customize WooCommerce**

- Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme - [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- Customizing WooCommerce - [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customizing-woocommerce-best-practices/)

Comment: I have changed the file structure, and included all the necessary files. Still having the same problem. any suggestions? the updated code is in the git repository at https://github.com/naderae/elbe-collections

Comment: page.php is the general file which shows all pages if no template assigned. I found that your page.php has the code statement `get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );` there is no template-parts folder in your theme. if no such file then simply replace the statement with `the_content();`

Comment: all the pages are showing up now! however ,there no being applied to them. do you know why this could be? thanks for you responses, very helpful

Comment: open all files and clean the code. In order to make a page entirely different from the default page use custom template. do not write everything in page.php or single.php

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite woocommerce css you need to add a woocommerce folder to your theme. And go from there. 
Woocommerce will also always use their own templates so the easiest way to change the layout is to use a child-plugin from woocommerce.

Comment: I have changed the file structure, and included all the necessary files. Still having the same problem. any suggestions? the updated code is in the git repository at https://github.com/naderae/elbe-collections

Comment: In order to change Woocommerce you must create a folder in your theme called 'woocommerce' if you put woocommerce.php in root folder of your theme it will not have effect. Also, when you want to change for example templates from the woocommerce/templates folder. You must put all those files in the woocommerce folder inside your theme. Do not create woocommerce/templates... But put everything in the "woocommerce" folder inside your theme. You find more information here... https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/